# Why the following args could not be parsed as stacks

Tags: ros, pocketsphinx

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
My name is Daniel Holanda. I'm a beginner using ROS and I have a problem that might be simple to solve.
I'm trying to install pocketsphinx using the tutorial at  pirobot.org/blog/0022/
When I type "rosmake --rosdep-install pocketsphinx" I have the following problem:

[ rosmake ] Packages requested are: ['pocketsphinx']
[ rosmake ] Logging to directory/home/daniel/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20130117-180252
[ rosmake ] Expanded args ['pocketsphinx'] to:
[]
[ rosmake ] WARNING: The following args could not be parsed as stacks or packages: ['pocketsphinx']
[ rosmake ] ERROR: No arguments could be parsed into valid package or stack names.

I'm using Ubuntu 11.10 Gnome and Ros Electric.

Thank you for the help,

Dan

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/52666/why-the-following-args-could-not-be-parsed-as-stacks/) by [danielhn1992](https://answers.ros.org/users/3994/danielhn1992/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-01-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, this is the same issue as [this question](http://answers.ros.org/question/28315/rosmake-pocketsphinx-issue/), and strangely enough, the same exact package.  ROS doesn't know where to look for the package you downloaded.  You have to set the environment variable ROS_PACKAGE_PATH to tell it where to look. Read about environment variables [here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/EnvironmentVariables).  Note that once you switch to the new ROS version, groovy, you won't have to do this.

---

Originally posted by [thebyohazard](https://answers.ros.org/users/1483/thebyohazard/) with karma: 3562 on 2013-01-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1